# The frequency of the given words in a txt file

Tags: c

As i said in the title I have to find the frequency of the given words(in a file) in another file

First file(called file (wow i know ))

```
3
watch
words
become
```

And second file(file1)

```
watch become words
watch words become
watch words watch
become
watch
become
```

This is what i have done so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100


typedef struct {
char word[N+1];
int occurrences;
  } index_t;

 int main()
{
int i=0,j=0;
FILE *file;
FILE *file1;
file=fopen("file","r");
file1=fopen("file1","r");

if(file1==NULL || file==NULL)
{
    printf("Error in the file");
    exit(1);
}
int n;
fscanf(file,"%d",&n);

index_t v[n];
char str[N];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    fscanf(file,"%s",v[i].word);
    v[i].occurrences=0;
    while(fscanf(file1,"%s",str)!=EOF)
    {
        if(strcmp(v[i].word,str)==0)
        {
            v[i].occurrences++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s:%d occurrences\n",v[i].word,v[i].occurrences);
}

return 0;
}
```

Thing is that it only works for the first word and not for the others. Can someone point out what i can do to fix this?

Comment: Hi, what is mean of 3 at the first line in first file?

Comment: @Whozcry Number of words in that file

Comment: To make your code work, you could just `rewind(file1);` after the `while` loop. But in that case you don't really need the structure definition, or the array of those structures. If you're supposed to be using an array of structs, then you should open the first file, read the first file into the array of structs, and close the first file. Then open the second file, and compare every word in the second file with the words in the array of structures.

Comment: From an efficiency standpoint, you certainly don't want to loop over the words in `file` and then in a nested loop loop over every word in `file1` (where for every word in `file` you loop over every word in `file1`). Far better to create a struct (e.g. `struct word_freq { char word[30]; int count };` and create an array of them (dynamically preferred) and read each word in `file1` and get the frequency `count` and then read `file` and simply get the `count` of each word that appears from your array.

Comment: @Severjan Lici, `fscanf(file,"%s",v[i].word);` without a width limit is bad, like the evil `gets()`.  Use a with: `fscanf(file,"%100s",v[i].word);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying out your code, it appears that the sequence of searching was incorrect.  With that, following is refactored code that maps out a sequence of events to first build the array of test words and then a loop structure to read and then test the text file for the number of word occurrences.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100

typedef struct
{
    char word[N+1];
    int occurrences;
} index_t;

int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[N];
    FILE *file;
    FILE *file1;
    file  = fopen("file","r");
    file1 = fopen("file1","r");

    if(file1==NULL || file==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in the file");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Acquire the number of test words */

    fscanf(file,"%d",&n);

    index_t v[n];

    /* Next, read and store each test word in the structure with the counter initialized to zero */

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file,"%s",v[i].word);
        v[i].occurrences=0;
    }

    /* Now, read the document file and the check for the number of occurences of each test word */

    while(fscanf(file1,"%s",str)!=EOF)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(v[i].word,str)==0)
            {
                v[i].occurrences++;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Finally, list out the test words and the number of occurences of each test word */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s:%d occurrences\n",v[i].word,v[i].occurrences);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Mainly, the tasks to be performed were split out more succinctly, but the major refactoring point was changing the "for and while" loop sequence when reading the text file to a "while and for" sequence.

With the refactored code, following was the terminal output.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Frequency/bin/Release$ ./Frequency 
watch:5 occurrences
words:3 occurrences
become:4 occurrences
```

Give that a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: See [width concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762862/the-frequency-of-the-given-words-in-a-txt-file#comment133650756_75762862).